# LINQ: find all checked checkboxes in a GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, webforms, ienumerable

Consider the current algorithm below that iterates through a `GridView`'s rows to find whether the contained `Checkbox` is selected/checked.

```
List<int> checkedIDs = new List<int>();

foreach (GridViewRow msgRow in messagesGrid.Rows)
{
  CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)msgRow.FindControl("chkUpdateStatus");
  if (chk.Checked){
   //we want the GridViewRow's DataKey value
   checkedMsgIDs.Add(int.Parse(messagesGrid.DataKeys[msgRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
  }
}
```

This works as expected: you're left with a fully populated `List<int>`.

**Question**: How would you or could you re-write or improve this algorithm using LINQ to search the `GridView` for all the rows who have their `Checkbox` selected/checked?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you're not going to get any performance improvement from this, but it might make it *slightly* easier to read:

```
var checkedIDs = from GridViewRow msgRow in messagesGrid.Rows
                 where ((CheckBox)msgRow.FindControl("chkUpdateStatus")).Checked
                 select Int32.Parse(messagesGrid.DataKeys[msgRow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
```

Again, not sure it makes a difference. Also, why are you converting to a string then to an int? Is there something `Convert.ToInt32` can't do for you?

Comment: Thanks LC!  `Convert.ToInt32` should work fine. Thanks for that enhancement as well!

Comment: This might sound silly but make sure that you have 'using System.Linq;' in place before trying to write this statement. I was able to write all of the Linq stuff without it complaining however when I tried to do the implicit cast (from GridViewRow msgRow) the compiler complained about not have a definition for 'Cast' in the GridViewRowCollection and nothing in Intelli-sense told me that I needed a using.

Answer (score 9):

I am not sure if Rows is IEnumerable they may not be, but I am going to assume they are

```
List<int> checkedIDs = messagesGrid.Rows
  .Where<GridViewRow>(i => (CheckBox)i.FindControl("chkUpdateStatus").Checked)
  .Select<GridViewRow, int>(i => return int.Parse(messagesGrid.DataKeys[i.RowIndex].Value.ToString()))
  .ToList<int>();
```

I just did this in notepad, there might be a compile error in there.  But this is how you could do the same thing with Linq.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the same as mine, but in method syntax and with a `ToList` on the end (and explicit generic type specifiers).

Comment: Yep, I saw that.  I like the method syntax to me it just looks cleaner.

Comment: It's untyped IEnumerable (as of .NET 4.0). You'd want to do `Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>().Where()...`

Answer (score 4):

I have something similar but I was using it in more than one place so I created an extension method.

```
public static void ActOnCheckedRows(this GridView gridView, string checkBoxId, Action<IEnumerable<int>> action)
{
   var checkedRows = from GridViewRow msgRow in gridView.Rows
                     where ((CheckBox)msgRow.FindControl(checkBoxId)).Checked
                     select (int) gridView.DataKeys[msgRow.RowIndex].Value;

    action(checkedRows);
}
```

So now I can do something with all the checked rows. The compiler is pretty good at deducing the types but occasionally I need to explicitly declare checkedRows as type IEnumerable.

```
gvTasksToBill.ActOnCheckedRows("RowLevelCheckBox", checkedRows =>
{
    foreach (int id in checkedRows)
    {
       // do something with id
    }
});
```